# CUA bindings for Conkeror during Gmail

Tags: binding, key-bindings, conkeror

How to have CUA style bindings for copy (C-c), paste (C-v) 
and possibly cut (C-x ), during Gmail rather than the EMACS bindings?
Understand cut as C-x is harder because it is a prefix.